# NGinX multiple sub uris to backend root

Tags: nginx, proxy, location, uri, reverse

I have an issue which I have not been able to solve and I hope I can get some hints to make this work. I have multiple backends that I would like to allow access through a reverse proxy. I can do this easily with multiple domains in NGinX like so:

```
server {
   listen  80;
   server_name     repo.test.local;

   location / {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass http://172.16.1.32;
                   break;
          }
   }
   server {
   listen  80;
   server_name     maprwebui.test.local;

   location / {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass https://172.16.1.104:8443;
                   break;
          }
   }
   server {
   listen  80;
   server_name     spark.test.local;

   location / {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass http://172.16.1.102:8080;
                   break;
          }
   }
   server {
   listen  80;
   server_name     yarnhistory.test.local;

   location / {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass http://172.16.1.202:19888;
                   break;
      }
   }
```

But I want to be able to do this with sub-URIs like so:

```
server {
    listen  80;     
    server_name     proxy.test.local;

   location /repo {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass http://172.16.1.32;
                    }
   location /maprui {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass https://172.16.1.104:8443;
                    }
   location /spark {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass http://172.16.1.102:8080;
                  }
   location /yarn {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass http://172.16.1.202:19888;
                  }
   }
```

I have tried everything I can think of to get this setup working, but I end up with 404s for URIs under these URIs, or the NginX application thinks that instead of trying to hit something like http://proxy.test.com/yarn/jobhistory, it reroutes to http://proxy.test.com/jobhistory

I have tried rewrite rules to see if they work and they don't either, or I'm doing them incorrectly. I have tested the following with no way for a fix:

```
    rewrite ^/yarn/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://172.16.1.202:19888;
```

Is there a way to get this to work, without having to touch the backend services that you want to expose, or without doing what I have working, with multiple domains?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, does the backend need to see http://172.16.1.202:19888/jobhistory or http://172.16.1.202:19888/yarn/jobhistory ?

Comment: Hi Josh,

Thanks for asking. On the proxy server, since I'm using the Uri yarn to decipher which backend I want to proxy, I would like for the front end to look like this:

http://proxy.test.local/yarn/jobhistory

The backend though does not have yarn and it would be

http://172.16.1.202:19888/jobhistory

I hope this clears any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may be quite simple, if I understand correctly. Nginx views what you are passing to `proxy_pass` as a host, versus a URI, perhaps try this:

```
server {
    listen  80;     
    server_name     proxy.test.local;

   location /repo {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass http://172.16.1.32/;
                    }
   location /maprui {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass https://172.16.1.104:8443/;
                    }
   location /spark {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass http://172.16.1.102:8080/;
                  }
   location /yarn {
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                   proxy_pass http://172.16.1.202:19888/;
                  }
   }
```

Note the `/` after the port. It should be as simple as that, what you're trying to do is certainly a common enough use case. Let me know if that doesn't work and we can try something else.

See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite) for more discussion

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the information. So I got things working partially with your setting. The difference that I made was by also adding the trailing / to the location side as well, like /yarn/. Issue now though is that additional calls or links within the same site yield 404s, for example I get 302 to /yarn/jobhistory, but jobhistory calls on static css files on the remote server at /static which end up as 404s on the proxy side because the URL referenced is proxy.test.local/static, not proxy.test.local/yarn/static. Is there a way to make all calls rewritable without having to define them?

Comment: Since CSS is not subject to the same origin rule, you could go back to host based passing for your CSS. Is all the CSS coming from /yarn or do the others also have CSS?